# Setting random size, color and position to a shape

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made this div element move to a random position on mouse click, however it doesn't respect the width and height of the entire screen and it goes out of it making it very unconfortable to be clicked. I want it to take the screen height and width into "consideration", so it doesn't go out of the page. I also want the div to get a random size, everytime it's clicked starting from a fixed higher size, and have it **always** going to a lower one. And finally for it to get random color on every click.

Html:

```
<div id="test">test div</div>
```

Css:

```
#test {
    position:absolute;
    width:100px;
    height:70px;
    background-color:#d2fcd9;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#test').click(function() {
    var docHeight = $(document).height(),
        docWidth = $(document).width(),
        $div = $('#test'),
        divWidth = $div.width(),
        divHeight = $div.height(),
        heightMax = docHeight - divHeight,
        widthMax = docWidth - divWidth;
    $div.css({
        left: Math.floor( Math.random() * widthMax ),
        top: Math.floor( Math.random() * heightMax )
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sould take `window` width and height instead of `document` sizes, document size can be bigger then window size.

To get random size on each click you should do basically the same as with position.

```
width: Math.floor(Math.random() * divWidth),
height: Math.floor(Math.random() * divHeight)
```

Each time it would give you lower values then before.

And finally to get random color you can generate it like this:

```
backgroundColor: "rgb(" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + "," + Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + "," + Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + ")"
```

Check the snippet below.

```js
$('#test').click(function() {
  
    var docHeight = $(document).height(),
        docWidth = $(document).width(),
        $div = $('#test'),
        divWidth = $div.width(),
        divHeight = $div.height(),
        heightMax = docHeight - divHeight,
        widthMax = docWidth - divWidth;
  
    $div.css({
        left: Math.floor( Math.random() * widthMax ),
        top: Math.floor( Math.random() * heightMax ),
        width: Math.floor(getRandomArbitrary(0.7, 1) * divWidth ),
        height: Math.floor(getRandomArbitrary(0.7, 1) * divHeight ),
        backgroundColor: "rgb(" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + "," + Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + "," + Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + ")"
    });
  
});

function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

```css
#test {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #d2fcd9;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="test">test div</div>
```

I have added function `getRandomArbitrary` to get random number from specified range, in this case from 0.7 to 1. That should require more clicks to get box dissapear.

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random).

Comment: Thanks for this, it really does what I asked to do. One little detail, I want it to proportionally smaller. For instance I don't want it to go from 1000 px to 1 px, but 1000px, then 835px, then 521px, etc. Random numbers, but ones that make sure that the box is still clickable up until you haven't pressed it one too many times.